# How do I make this run as a Java applet instead of a Java application?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I can't figure out how to get this to run as an applet, please help
I've been trying a bunch of things but nothing is working. I believe I have to make the `class extend Applet` but I'm not sure what to change after doing that

**EDIT: Nevermind I have solved the problem! :D**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HowMany {

   private JFrame mainJFrame;
   private JLabel headerJLabel;
   private JLabel statusJLabel;
   private JPanel controlJPanel;

   public HowMany() {
      prepareGUI();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){ /* The main part of the code */
      HowMany HowMany = new HowMany();  
      HowMany.showEventDemo();       
   }

   private void prepareGUI() {
      mainJFrame = new JFrame("Click the Button!"); /*Sets the applet title */
      mainJFrame.setSize(400,400); /* Sets the size of the applet */
      mainJFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

      headerJLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER ); //Centers the header JLabel
      statusJLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER); //Centers the status JLabel    

      statusJLabel.setSize(350,100); //Sets the size of the status JLabel
      mainJFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });    
      controlJPanel = new JPanel();
      controlJPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      mainJFrame.add(headerJLabel); //adds all the stuff to the applet
      mainJFrame.add(controlJPanel);
      mainJFrame.add(statusJLabel);
      mainJFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }

   private void showEventDemo() {
      headerJLabel.setText("Click the Button to add to the bottom text!");     /* Tells you to click */
      /* Click button */
      JButton clickButton = new JButton("Click Me!");

      clickButton.setActionCommand("Click Me!");

      clickButton.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener()); 
      /* Adds the buttons to the JFrame */
      controlJPanel.add(clickButton);     

      mainJFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }

   private class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener {
      int x = 0; //Sets the starting value of the # of times the button was clicked to 0
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String command = e.getActionCommand();  
         /* Displays how many times the button was clicked */
         if( command.equals( "Click Me!" ))  {
             x = x + 1;
             String m = Integer.toString(x);
            statusJLabel.setText("Times clicked: " + m);
         }
      }     
   }
}
```

Comment: *"I believe I have to make the `class extend Applet`"*  First step and already gone wrong.  Use `JApplet` instead if you wish to persist with this madness.  BTW - do you realize that Chrom, FF and soon(?) IE won't be able to launch applets?  The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (..from a link on a web page, **instead of** making an applet).

Comment: `System.exit(0);` That will never work in an applet..

Answer (score 0):

To make a java applet run you are going to need to run it on a web server.

This link shows oracles examples on how to make an applet which you should easily be able to follow to work with your example:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Also you can see on that page that if you are trying to run it as a local applet and have your java security set to high or very high it won't work. Something to keep in mind.